# command-execute error with straight.el

Tags: init-file, debugging, straight.el, emacs28

I have just tried to setup `magit` using `straight.el` in my init file as follows:

```lisp
(use-package magit
       :straight t
       :bind ("C-x g" . magit-status)
       :commands (magit-status magit-get-current-branch))
```

However upon restarting emacs (v28.1) on my macOS (Montery v12.2.1) I get the following error message:

```
command-execute: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, ../../../../../../../.emacs.d/straight/build/magit/magit-status
```

For some reason `straight.el` seems to be searching for the clone in several directories above the current one. It seems to be doing this to many other newly installed packages, e.g. `projectile`.

Note that my `~/.emacs.d` is symlinked to my dropbox folder in case that is relevant:

```bash
.emacs.d -> ~/DROPBOX/REPOS/dotfiles/.emacs.d
```

It seems that a [similar issue](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/701) has been flagged here, but I'm not sure what the resolution is. For reference [here](https://github.com/shamindras/ss_dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/myinit.el) is my init file.

How can this be rectified?

**Update:** I've cross-posted this [here](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/701#issuecomment-1160624744), since the comments to this post lead back to this thread. I will post any helpful responses on either thread to the other one to ensure that the responses are passed onto users with the same issue.

Comment: Do you have `find-file-visit-truename` set? If yes, try setting it to `nil`. You can check a related question. 
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69066/problem-loading-packages-with-emacs-28

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas - thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the same issue occurs. I placed your suggested line *before* setting up `straight.el`. Is that how you did it?. [Here](https://github.com/shamindras/ss_dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/myinit.el) is my init file in case that helps

Comment: Not answering your questions in any way, I just wanna mention that you can give `chemacs2` a try and perhaps you'll no longer need your .emacs.d symlink and then your problem might just go away.

Comment: Also [here](https://github.com/blaenk/dots/blob/master/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el#L60-L65) is another suggested [workaround](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/701#issuecomment-1094153050) from the thread I flagged above. I tried placing this after `straight.el` setup as per the repo above. It did not resolve this issue either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the solution that worked for me, based on the helpful suggestions by [@Swarnendu Biswas](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2292/swarnendu-biswas) above, and the github user `@croqaz` in [this thread](https://github.com/radian-software/straight.el/issues/701#issuecomment-1161467243).

In short, simply adding `(setq find-file-visit-truename nil)` was not enough for me. Crucially I had to delete the `straight` installation directory, and rebuild everything from scratch. As per my post in the mentioned thread, I performed the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Backup `~/.emacs.d` dir
2. Deleted the entire `~/.emacs.d/straight` dir.

- This is more than what @croqaz suggested (i.e. to just delete `~/.emacs.d/straight/build` dir only), but I just wanted to be quite cautious to resolve this issue.
- Re-installing everything from scratch took less than a minute for me. Thanks to `straight.el`

4. Ensure that `(setq find-file-visit-truename nil)` is included in my [init file](https://github.com/shamindras/ss_dotfiles/blob/0bd4566b75df0c04610099cbafe946659fe11d86/.emacs.d/myinit.el?rgh-link-date=2022-06-20T16%3A07%3A00Z#L131) [after bootstrapping](https://github.com/shamindras/ss_dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/myinit.el#L117-L129) `straight.el`.
5. Do a quick search for `setq find-file-visit-truename` and check that we have set it to `nil` and not `t` anywhere else.

   - I had it set to `t` in my `dired`, which I removed.
   - This did cause me issues, but were resolved after removing it and setting it to `nil` only once as per above.

I hope this provides some guidance for others when faced with this issue.